# How can I ignore a specific JSP validation error message in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, validation

I want to ignore a specific error message for all my files but I want that other error messages for these files are not affected!

my error message looks like this:

```
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/WEB-INF/da_taglib.tld"
```

and appears on this line in my JSP-files:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/da_taglib.tld" prefix="da" %>`
```

I searched in the preferences, but only found the option for disabling all error messages for certain files. (`Window-> Preferences -> General -> Validation`)

It would also be fine if i could disable the error group (`Can not find the tag library descriptor for *`)

Background: this error message appears because of a war-overlay. when i deploy it it works fine, but eclipse is not seeing the file, that's why the error appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for projects:

```
(right click) Properties -> Validation -> JSP Syntax -> Directives -> Unresolvable URI or tagdir
```

for workspace:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Web -> JSP Files -> Validation -> Directives -> Unresolvable URI or tagdir
```

Comment: worked for me! i set it to "warning". that way i can still see if something may be wrong with other URIs or tagdirs.